# passport session with websocket server library

Tags: node.js, websocket, passport.js

Could passport session be expected to work with a web socket library( https://github.com/websockets/ws )? We have a regular passport authentication setup: but the req.session.user sometimes shows up correctly in the websocket request and sometimes it does not.

We are initializing the websocket like this:

```
this.wss = new WebSocketServer({
  server: this.server, // This is the express app
  verifyClient: function(info, done) {
    self.session_parser(info.req, {}, function() {
      console.log('VERIFY ', info.req.session);
      // allow connection only if session is valid and a user is logged in
      done(info.req.session && info.req.session.passport &&
        info.req.session.passport.user &&
        info.req.session.passport.user.id);
    });
  }
});
```

The problems is that info.req.session.user shows up correctly for some web socket requests and sometimes it does not in the verifyClient function. req.session always shows up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is in dev env?

If you use `memorystore` session it cleaned after app reload. You can switch to `session-file-store` but it usually don't store on `res.redirect()`

In other cases you must check is session don't expire on server.